# Java Swing JtextField inset

Tags: java, swing, border, margin, jtextfield

I am working with Netbeans GUI and I would like to add 3 pixels of space at the beginning of my jTextField :

[image]

I have tryied with setMargin, setInset in the GUI but it doesn't change anything.

I have another question, why the bottom right border is not rounded ? here is my code :

```
Border roundedBorder = new LineBorder(new Color(210,210,210), 1, true);
researchTextField.setBorder(roundedBorder);
```

thank you very much,

Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `setMargin(...)` should work.

However, if you are also using a Border then that may be the problem.

Try using a `CompoundBorder` where the inner border is an EmptyBorder() and the outer border is your other border. For example:

```
Border rounded = new LineBorder(new Color(210,210,210), 1, true);
Border empty = new EmptyBorder(0, 3, 0, 0);
Border border = new CompoundBorder(rounded, empty);
textField.setBorder(border);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

> why the bottom right border is not rounded ?

I'm not sure why your bottom/right is not rounded. Using the Metal LAF on XP the right borders (top and bottom) appear rounded but the left borders are not rounded. When I use a border size of 2 or more all corners appear equally rounded.

Answer (score 4):

`setMargin(Inset myInset)` worked for me:

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFieldFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(textfield);

      textfield.setMargin(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```