# Java Swing rounded border for Jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, rounded-corners

When I do :

```
LineBorder lineBorder =new LineBorder(Color.white, 8, true);
jTextField2.setBorder(lineBorder );
```

I get this result like:

[image]

How can I have rounded borders without the squared corners visible and the text half cut ?

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Comment: -1, You asked this question a couple of weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305460/java-swing-jtextfield-inset/8305672#8305672

Comment: @camickr thanks, didn't recognize the duplicate - will vote to close this ..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can override `JTextFiled` build your own Rounded corner `JTextField`. You have to override it's `paintComponent()`, `paintBorder()`, and `contains()` methods. You need to draw roundRect as the shape of text field.

Example:

```
public class RoundJTextField extends JTextField {
    private Shape shape;
    public RoundJTextField(int size) {
        super(size);
        setOpaque(false); // As suggested by @AVD in comment.
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(getBackground());
         g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 15, 15);
         super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
         g.setColor(getForeground());
         g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 15, 15);
    }
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
         if (shape == null || !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
             shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, 15, 15);
         }
         return shape.contains(x, y);
    }
}
```

To see this in effect:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rounded corner text filed demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JTextField field = new RoundJTextField(15);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple example here:
http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com.ar/2012/03/rounded-border-for-jtextfield.html

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @Harry Joy's answer - just going the full distance, as [outlined in a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416295/component-painting-outside-custom-border)

- define a border type which exposes a shape
- make the component aware of a possibly shaped border
- if it detects the shaped border, take over the background painting in paintComponent inside the shape (no need to touch paintBorder)

Answer (score 1):

This will modify any JTextField that you create in the entire application

Drop it just at the beginning of your very first window, it will affect every JTextField.

```
    UIManager.put("TextField.background", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("TextField.border", BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            new CustomeBorder(), 
            new EmptyBorder(new Insets(4,4,4,4))));
```

The custom border

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static class CustomeBorder extends AbstractBorder{
    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y,
            int width, int height) {
        super.paintBorder(c, g, x, y, width, height);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setPaint(COLOR_BORDE_SIMPLE);
        Shape shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, c.getWidth()-1, c.getHeight()-1,9, 9);
        g2d.draw(shape);
    }
}
```