# JTextField with rounded corner preserving shadows

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, rounded-corners

I need to have a rounded corner text field and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515601/java-swing-rounded-border-for-jtextfield) the problem is that with this solution I lose all the standard `JTextField` shadows.

Does anyone know how to restore them?

Comment: please whats **the problem is that with this solution I lose all the standard JTextField shadows.**, for bettter help sooner post an `SSCCE` and/or with `picture` about desired shadows, please ensure us that we talking about `Standard Look and Feels`, excluding `Nimbus L&F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply replace original textfield border without losing the shadow. You will have to apply some specific border with your own shadow-like effect or even modify the UI so it paints the shadow around the field.

Here is a simple example of shadow-like UI for textfield:

```
public static class RoundedFieldUI extends BasicTextFieldUI
{
    private int round = 5;
    private int shadeWidth = 2;
    private int textSpacing = 3;

    public void installUI ( JComponent c )
    {
        super.installUI ( c );

        c.setOpaque ( false );

        int s = shadeWidth + 1 + textSpacing;
        c.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( s, s, s, s ) );
    }

    protected void paintSafely ( Graphics g )
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        Shape border = getBorderShape ();

        Stroke os = g2d.getStroke ();
        g2d.setStroke ( new BasicStroke ( shadeWidth * 2 ) );
        g2d.setPaint ( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        g2d.draw ( border );
        g2d.setStroke ( os );

        g2d.setPaint ( Color.WHITE );
        g2d.fill ( border );

        g2d.setPaint ( Color.BLACK );
        g2d.draw ( border );

        super.paintSafely ( g );
    }

    private Shape getBorderShape ()
    {
        JTextComponent component = getComponent ();
        if ( round > 0 )
        {
            return new RoundRectangle2D.Double ( shadeWidth, shadeWidth,
                    component.getWidth () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1,
                    component.getHeight () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1, round * 2, round * 2 );
        }
        else
        {
            return new Rectangle2D.Double ( shadeWidth, shadeWidth,
                    component.getWidth () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1,
                    component.getHeight () - shadeWidth * 2 - 1 );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout ( 5, 5 ) );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 50, 50, 50, 50 ) );
        frame.add ( panel );

        panel.add ( new JLabel ( "Field:" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

        JTextField field = new JTextField ( 20 );
        field.setUI ( new RoundedFieldUI () );
        panel.add ( field );

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better now but in the default `JTextFiled` use inner shadows not shadows outside the textfield. Thanks!!

Comment: @Luca That is just an example, you can modify it in any way you want

Comment: @Luca its hard for this specific example. You can simply paint two separate rounded rectangles with different colors (dark for border and light for shadow) close to each other. That will create the shadow visual effect. And just fill the background inside