# JTextField customization issue

Tags: java, swing, awt, border, jtextfield

I have made a frame and put a button and a text field in it.
I am using the `setMargin` method to set a margin between the caret and the border of the text field and works perfectly fine until I add a border to it.

After adding the border the `setMargin` call method does not work.

Could you please help me understand the origin of the issue and find an alternative of having both a border and a certain margin?

```
public class main extends JFrame  {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        JTextField textfield0;
        JButton button0;
        
        Border border7=BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(new Color(0xA524FF), 2, 5, 4, true);
        Border border8=BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder();
        Border border01=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
        Border border02=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW);
        Border border9=BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border01, border02);
        
        textfield0=new JTextField();
        textfield0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,30));
        textfield0.setFont(new Font("Consolas",Font.BOLD,15));
        textfield0.setCaretColor(Color.RED);
        textfield0.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        textfield0.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        textfield0.setText("name");
        //textfield0.setBorder(border9);
        textfield0.setSelectedTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        textfield0.setMargin(new Insets(0,7,0,5));
        textfield0.setCaretPosition(0);
        textfield0.setSelectionColor(Color.PINK);

        button0=new JButton();
        button0.setText("submit");
        button0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));    
        button0.setFocusable(false);
        button0.setBackground(textfield0.getBackground());
        button0.setFont(textfield0.getFont());
        button0.setBorder(textfield0.getBorder());
        
        JFrame frame00=new JFrame();
        frame00.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame00.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        frame00.add(button0);
        frame00.add(textfield0);
        frame00.pack();
        frame00.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *find an alternative of having both a border and a certain margin?* - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305460/java-swing-jtextfield-inset/8305672#8305672

Comment: For situations like this, I'd create a `JPanel`, add the component to the panel as the only child, then set a border(1) to **the panel.** 1) Or a compound border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find an answer for this in the JavaDoc which requires a few extra steps:

> Sets margin space between the text component's border and its text.
> The text component's default Border object will use this value to
> create the proper margin. **However, if a non-default border is set on
> the text component, it is that Border object's responsibility to
> create the appropriate margin space** (else this property will
> effectively be ignored).

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-

And to do the above we can do one of two things, we can use a compound border as shown here: [Java Swing - setting margins on TextArea with Line Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274750/java-swing-setting-margins-on-textarea-with-line-border) or we can take the following steps:

> Overriding both `AbstractBorder.getBorderInsets(Component c)` and
> `AbstractBorder.getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets)` to
> provide the correct insets

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html#custom

I strongly recommend reading through the above link to get a better understanding of borders and how you can work with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the javadoc for Border, it states: "Use EmptyBorder to create a plain border (this mechanism replaces its predecessor, setInsets)"

So you can either use a CompoundBorder with a PlainBorder and the one you are setting, or override getBorderInsets(Component c) on your existing Border